# log4j2 xml does not recognize program arguments

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j2

I have a java spring application and I want to pass one of my program arguments to log4j2.xml file

I start it with that command:

`nohup java -DremoteMapIp=120.0.1 -Dserver.port=9013 -Dspring.profiles.active=tt-test -jar ttsis-rows.jar`

in my **tt-test.yaml** file i configured logging as:

```
logging:
  config: classpath:fileAppender.xml
```

and my **fileAppender.xml** file

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>logs/ttsis-rows-${sys:server.port:-noPort}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>false</cleanHistoryOnStart>
            <fileNamePattern>ttsis-rows-${sys:server.port:-noPort}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

My problem is my log file is always created as "ttsis-rows-noPort.log" (configured by file tag in fileAppender.xml) and program argument does not recognized by log4j.
Any idea how to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `${server.port}` instead of `${sys:server.port:-noPort}`

Comment: Man you are a wizard :D , that worked thank you so much !